# Expose / Reuse html Block with gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I am using a html-Block (Service Level Agreement) within a component. All good and working.

I like to have this block in a separated html-file und use it then in the component but also

'publicly' available so a mobile app could fetch this single file too and show its content in the app.

Main reason is to have only one file to maintain with all the SLA Texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place HTML code in your React component by using [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Example:

```
import htmlFile from "./path/to/html/file.html";

const HtmlDiv = () =>  (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "Hello" }}></div>
);
```